# list systemd RuntimeDirectory mounts

Tags: systemd, systemd-mount

I have a systemd service with this declaration:

```
RuntimeDirectory=plex
RuntimeDirectoryMode=750
```

which creates the in memory directory `/run/plex`.

How would I list the capabilities of this mount point as I would do with `mount -l`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RuntimeDirectory=` directive does not create a new mount, it only creates a new directory under the existing `/run`. So, in a way, you're just reusing space from the existing `/run`.

In other words, look for `/run` in `mount -l` output to see the options of the mountpoint where `/run/plex` lives.

You can also use the [`findmnt(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/findmnt) command and pass it the full path with `-T` to show where the mount point is and its options. For example:

```
$ findmnt -T /run/plex
TARGET SOURCE FSTYPE OPTIONS
/run   tmpfs  tmpfs  rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,mode=755
```

If you want to know how much space has been allocated for the in-memory tmpfs, you can use the [`df(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/df) command:

```
$ df -h /run/plex
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           3.9G  612K  3.9G   1% /run
```